# Sorting wordpress posts by date published

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

im using the following code to display my posts on a page in wordpress that use a featured image:

```
$mypages = get_pages( array() );

if ( !empty( $mypages ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $mypages as $mypage ) {
        if ( get_the_post_thumbnail( $mypage->ID ) ) {

            echo '<div class="featured-container">';


                echo '<div class="featured-image">';

                    echo '<li><a class="feat-hover" href="' . get_permalink( $mypage->ID ) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $mypage->ID ) . '</a></li>';

                echo '</div>';



                echo '<div class="featured-text">';

                    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $mypage->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title($mypage->ID ) . '</a>';

                echo '</div>';

            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

but before printing this information out i want to sort the $mypages array so that they display by date published.  ive tried this code:

```
    <?php $args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'post_date',
); 

$mypages = get_pages($args); 
?>
```

but it doesnt seem to work, am i missing something or doing this the wrong way?

thanks in advance.

FULL CODE BEING USED:

```
$args = array(

        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'sort_column' => 'post_date'

);

$mypages = get_pages( array($args) );

if ( !empty( $mypages ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $mypages as $mypage ) {
        if ( get_the_post_thumbnail( $mypage->ID ) ) {

            echo '<div class="featured-container">';


                echo '<div class="featured-image">';

                    echo '<li><a class="feat-hover" href="' . get_permalink( $mypage->ID ) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $mypage->ID ) . '</a></li>';

                echo '</div>';



                echo '<div class="featured-text">';

                    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $mypage->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title($mypage->ID ) . '</a>';

                echo '</div>';

            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't seem to work"? Your syntax is correct...How are the posts output?

Comment: They are still ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Where are you placing the second block of code you posted above?

Comment: the second block is place above the first il edit the first post so you can see my whole code now.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're passing `$args` into another `array()`. You only need to pass in the `$args` directly, since it's already an `array()`. Change the top block of code to:

```
$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'post_date'
);

$mypages = get_pages( $args );
```